# MySQL Query: Display Specific Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have five columns in my table.

Column 1: Name of Store and columns 2 to 5: Store Types

For Name of Store, it will basically just contain the name of the stores. For columns 2-5, it will contain either YES or NO depending on what store type it is. For example:

```
StoreName    | Clot. | Food | App. | Shoes 
Mcdonalds    |  NO   | YES  |  NO  |  NO
MC ShoeStore |  NO   | NO   |  NO  |  YES
```

Now I want to come up with a query wherein I'd display all stores starting with the letter M and their store type without the other store type with 'NO' in it appearing.

I only know:

```
SELECT NameOfStore from table where NameOfStore LIKE '%m'
```

I'm not sure on how I'm going to display the store type where it contains a YES. or is that possible?

Comment: Could a store have more than one 'yes'? Like `CLOTHING = YES` and `SHOES = YES` for the same store?

Comment: It is very much possible that a store sellsl both shoes and clothes so yes.

Comment: OK - How would you want to present that in your results?

Comment: What I would want to happen is to display the name of store and then beside it is its store type but I'm not sure if it's possible because there is no specific column delegated or named "Store Type:. It's just the type of stores individually presented.

Comment: Just to add some context to @Nicarus comment, if a shop sells both clothing and shoes, would the data in a `StoreType` column look like this for example: "Clothing, Shoes" using a comma or some other delimiter to separate the values? As Nicarus asked, how is this data expected to be presented?

Comment: Oh right. Okay. So far what it does it display the first condition that appears. It would be better if will be separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a case statement. Also, your `WHERE` clause criteria was wrong.

```
SELECT
    NameOfStore,
    CASE
        WHEN Clothes = 'YES' THEN 'Clothes'
        WHEN Fastfood = 'YES' THEN 'Fastfood'
        WHEN Appliances = 'YES' THEN 'Appliances'
        WHEN Shoes = 'YES' THEN 'Shoes'
    END AS TypeOfStore
FROM
    table
WHERE
    LOWER(NameOfStore) LIKE 'm%';
```

**Handling multiple store types for a single store:**

```
SELECT
    NameOfStore,
    CONCAT_WS(' & ', --This is the separator to use - you can replace this with whatever
    CASE WHEN Clothes = 'YES' THEN 'Clothes' END,
    CASE WHEN Fastfood = 'YES' THEN 'Fastfood' END,
    CASE WHEN Appliances = 'YES' THEN 'Appliances' END,
    CASE WHEN Shoes = 'YES' THEN 'Shoes' END
    ) AS TypeOfStore
FROM
    table
WHERE
    LOWER(NameOfStore) LIKE 'm%';
```

Your output would look something like:

```
NameOfStore   |   TypeOfStore
-----------------------------
McDonalds     |   Fastfood
Mike's Shop   |   Clothes & Shoes
```

Comment: `LOWER()` lowercases a string. Using just `LIKE 'm%'` would only match stores with a lowercase 'm' at the beginning of the name. I made the store name lowercase to match any store with a lower or uppercase 'm' at the beginning of the name

Comment: @Nicaurus okay the CONCAT_WS worked but I am not sure what the proper syntax is if I have to add another column after TypeOfStore with the same process. To visualize easier, think of it as I need to display the TypeOfStore column twice, same cases.

Answer (score 1):

To be more flexible I would suggest you first change the structure of your data.

Table **store**

```
+--+---------+-------------+
|id|name     |store_type_id|
+--+---------+-------------+
| 1|Mcdonalds|            2|
| 2|Mc Shoes |            4|
```

Table **store_type**

```
+--+-----------+
|id|name       |
+--+-----------+
| 1|Clothing   |
| 2|Fastfood   |
| 3|Applicances|
| 4|Shoes      |
```

Then you can simply join the store types to the stores.

```
SELECT
    store.name,
    store_type.name AS store_type
FROM
    store
    LEFT JOIN store_type ON store.store_type_id = store_type.id
```

If a store can have more than one type you would use an [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) to link the two instead of the `store_type_id` column in the store table.

Table **store_store_types**

```
+--------+-------------+
|store_id|store_type_id|
+--------+-------------+
|       1|            2|
|       2|            1|
|       2|            4|
```

And the query...

```
SELECT
    store.name,
    store_type.name AS store_type
FROM
    store
    LEFT JOIN store_store_type rel ON store.id = rel.store_id
    LEFT JOIN store_type ON rel.store_type_id = store_type.id
```